# Correct GSON call to convert from JSON objects to Java objects

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Please suggest the correct method to call GSON here to convert to the java object.

```
final JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonBody.put("user",user);
        jsonBody.put("password",pass);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "CheckForResponse: "+jsonBody.toString());
    JsonObjectRequest JSONObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            Log.d("Response",response.toString());

//How to call GSON here?

            Token token = new Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(response), Token.class);

            Token token1 = new Token();
            User user1 = new User();
            Log.d(TAG, "Triplet: onCreate: "+token1.getToken());
            Log.d(TAG, "Triplet: onCreate: "+user1.getUsername());

            Toast.makeText(TLogin.this, "InsideResponse : Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent goToMainScreen = new Intent(TLogin.this,GameMenu.class);
            startActivity(goToMainScreen);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if(error != null && error.getMessage() != null)
            {
                Log.e("Response error", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    );
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(JSONObjectRequest);
```

### post script: I have created POJO classes for the getter and setter for java object from the JSON.

JSON data

```
{
"token":"ezI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2Vn0.028Kmtp",

"user":
{
    "id":"57a5ff5",
    "avatar":10,
    "username":"abc",
    "rating":12,
    "facebookPicture":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.5\/11642925\/picture?type=square&width=200&height=200"
}
}
```

POJO Class
Token.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
            @Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
            public class Token {

            @SerializedName("token")
            @Expose
            private String token;
            @SerializedName("user")
            @Expose
            private User user;

            /**
            * 
            * @return
            * The token
            */
            public String getToken() {
            return token;
            }

            /**
            * 
            * @param token
            * The token
            */
            public void setToken(String token) {
            this.token = token;
            }

            /**
            * 
            * @return
            * The user
            */
            public User getUser() {
            return user;
            }

            /**
            * 
            * @param user
            * The user
            */
            public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
            }

            }
```

User.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
            @Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
            public class User {

            @SerializedName("id")
            @Expose
            private String id;
            @SerializedName("avatar")
            @Expose
            private Integer avatar;
            @SerializedName("username")
            @Expose
            private String username;
            @SerializedName("rating")
            @Expose
            private Integer rating;
            @SerializedName("facebookPicture")
            @Expose
            private String facebookPicture;

            /**
            * 
            * @return
            * The id
            */
            public String getId() {
            return id;
            }

            /**
            * 
            * @param id
            * The id
            */
            public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
            }

            /**
            * 
            * @return
            * The avatar
            */
            public Integer getAvatar() {
            return avatar;
            }

            /**
            * 
            * @param avatar
            * The avatar
            */
            public void setAvatar(Integer avatar) {
            this.avatar = avatar;
            }

            /**
            * 
            * @return
            * The username
            */
            public String getUsername() {
            return username;
            }

            /**
            * 
            * @param username
            * The username
            */
            public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
            }

            /**
            * 
            * @return
            * The rating
            */
            public Integer getRating() {
            return rating;
            }

            /**
            * 
            * @param rating
            * The rating
            */
            public void setRating(Integer rating) {
            this.rating = rating;
            }

            /**
            * 
            * @return
            * The facebookPicture
            */
            public String getFacebookPicture() {
            return facebookPicture;
            }

            /**
            * 
            * @param facebookPicture
            * The facebookPicture
            */
            public void setFacebookPicture(String facebookPicture) {
            this.facebookPicture = facebookPicture;
            }

            }
```

Comment: This looks fine.. are you getting any errors?

Comment: Log.d(TAG, "Triplet: onCreate: "+token1.getToken()); it shows empty data values

Comment: @SripadRaj so i'm afraid if it is inserting the values.

Comment: are you getting response in json properly? if yes post your json response. and your `Token` POJO class.

Comment: @SripadRaj added the code. please check the above update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Insted of

```
Log.d(TAG, "Triplet: onCreate: "+token1.getToken());
Log.d(TAG, "Triplet: onCreate: "+user1.getUsername());
```

> use

```
Log.d(TAG, "Triplet: onCreate: "+token.getToken());
Log.d(TAG, "Triplet: onCreate: "+token.getUser().getUsername());
```

Comment: And can I use this in any class as global object?

Comment: there is two possibility to use in other class
1) by defining it public static
2) define object in application level class and then use from that

Comment: @Prateekro did you get answer?